# My application specialized icons no longer show in Dock. Instead it is showing default icons in the dock

Tags: macos, applications, dock, icon, command-line

Recently Application-specific icons are not appearing in the dock. Instead it's showing the generic icon for many apps I'm running. The icons for many apps is this.

[image]

Why are my app-specific icons no longer showing in the dock.  I tried

> `killall Dock`

but that only changed one specific icon. There are still 16 more occurrences of these generic icons. I also tried `

> defaults delete com.apple.dock; killall Dock

but to no avail.

Comment: Are the app icons in /Applications showing generic icons too?

Comment: no. The Applications folder shows the correct icons.